# How to I write a regular expression in Python 2.7 to return two words in a string with an underscore between them

Tags: python, regex, string

I have strings consistent with this example:

```
>>> s = "plant yard !!@ blah HELLO OS=puffin_CuteDeer_cat_anteater"
```

Every string has the "OS=" expression and its latter part comprises words linked by underscores. The first part of the string up to "OS=" and the actual words linked by underscores differ among strings.

I want to write a regular expression with the 're' module to ignore the first part of the string up to the  pattern part, and then return the first two words within that pattern maintaining the underscore between them.

I want:

```
>>> 'puffin_CuteDeer'
```

I can get rid of the first part, and am getting close (I think) to handling the  pattern part. Here's what I have and what it returns:

```
>>> example = re.search('(?<=OS=)(.*(?=_))',s)
>>> example.group(0)
>>> 'puffin_CuteDeer_cat'
```

I have tried many, many different possibilities and none of them are working.

I was surprised that

```
>>> example = re.search('(?<=OS=)(.*(?=_){2})',s)
```

did not work.

Your help is sincerely appreciated.

Update: I realize that there are non-regex ways of obtaining the desired output. However, for reasons that are probably beyond the scope of the question, I think regex is the best choice for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
(?<=OS=)[^_]+_[^_]+
```

- The zero-width positive lookbehind, `(?<=OS=)`, matches `OS=`
- `[^_]+` matches one or more characters upto next `_`, `_` matches a literal `_`

**Example:**

```
In [90]: s
Out[90]: 'plant yard !!@ blah HELLO OS=puffin_CuteDeer_cat_anteater'

In [91]: re.search(r'(?<=OS=)[^_]+_[^_]+', s).group()
Out[91]: 'puffin_CuteDeer'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this option. This works better in my case than re.findall, I think, because I do not need to produce a list. Thank you for your kind explanation of [^...]. I could not understand that from the documentation.

Comment: @17thLvlBotanist No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = "plant yard !!@ blah HELLO OS=puffin_CuteDeer_cat_anteater"
s = re.findall('(?<=OS\=)[a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+', s)[0]
```

Output:

```
'puffin_CuteDeer'
```

Comment: Oh, this works perfectly. Thank you so much! Now that I see how to developed the correct expression for the pattern, I assume that perhaps \w can replace [a-zA-Z]. I will explore that as well. Thanks again!

Comment: @17thLvlBotanist glad to help! However, you do not want to replace `[a-zA-Z]` with `\w`, as the latter will match `_`, thus `\w+` at the end will, in this case, find `puffin_CuteDeer_cat_anteater`, which is not the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

The following uses a capturing group `(...)` and negation `[^...]` to get the desired part:

```
>>> re.search(r'OS=([^_]+_[^_]+)', s).group(1)
'puffin_CuteDeer'
```

Comment: As with @heemayl, I really appreciate this answer and the explanation of the [^...] expression element.

Answer (score 0):

Regex may not be necessary:

```
s = "plant yard !!@ blah HELLO OS=puffin_CuteDeer_cat_anteater"

right_side = s.split("=")[-1]
"_".join(right_side.split("_")[:2])
# 'puffin_CuteDeer'
```

Comment: Thank you. The actual situation is a little more complex, and I wanted to avoid the list construction. I will add that fact to the original question.

Comment: Yes, which is why I think that the options presented by schwobaseggl and heemayl are ultimately more suitable for my purposes.